# Show that two affine varieties are not isomorphic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X=\mathbb{V}(xy(x-y))\subseteq\mathbb{A}^2$, $Y=\mathbb{V}(xy,yz,zx)\subseteq\mathbb{A}^3$. The question is about showing that $X$ and $Y$ are not isomorphic. Suppose for a contradiction $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic. By computing the dimension of tangent space, $(0,0)\in X$ must be mapped to $(0,0,0)\in Y$. How can one continue and show that this is a contradiction?

Comment: You're very close to a full solution already- can you compute what the dimension of the tangent space at each of those points? When you do that, what do you get?

Comment: $2$ and $3$ respectively?

Comment: Correct. Can you see why this implies these two varieties can't be isomorphic?

Comment: I can't see a mathematically rigorous way to prove that the dimension of tangent space (not Krull dimension) must be preserved by isomorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two varieties were isomorphic, then the local rings of the corresponding points would be isomorphic. As the dimension of the tangent space $(\mathfrak{m}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x^2)^*$ is equal to the minimal number of generators of the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, which is clearly an isomorphism invariant of local rings, we see that isomorphisms of varieties must preserve the dimensions of the tangent space at each point.